# ASP.NET - Data Grid and Drop Down list

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, drop-down-menu

I am working on a web page that has a data grid and have a need to do
the following:

- Have a column that is a drop down when the grid loads (no need to click edit)
- This column is bound to a column from the data query (everything up
  to this point works fine)
- I know need to add more values to this drop down from another
  dataset (so the user can change the value if required)
- These values come from a query to another table in the database. The
  values will be same for all the rows in the table, these values are
  based on a master key for the complete webpage.

As an example:

table 1 has:

Mangoes $12
Apricots $13
Peaches $14

This is on the grid.

The other table has:

Prices

12
13
14
15
16

I want these values from the prices table to appear in the drop down
for table 1 in the data grid, with the current values as the selected
item.

Any ideas will help. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know,
U should better change ur table design.
If ur fruit table is concern with price id, then u can easily select the item from dropdown with current value in fruit table.

Fruit                 
    PriceId   
                                                PriceId
        Price 
  


------------------------                                            --------------------                                        





 
    Mangoes                 
    1  
              <---------------------> 
          1
                12 
  



 
    Apricots                  
    2 

          <---------------------> 
          2
                13 
  




 
    Peaches                  
    3 
              <---------------------> 
          3
                14

then it is easier to list all price in dropdown list 
and also easier to choose selected price based on PriceId from Fruit table.

Sound like little confuse? let me know, if anything u want?
Hope it works!

Comment: Dear Thura - thanks for the idea. But unfortunately cannot change the database as it is come pre designed. Have to work with the existing data structure. At this point I have got the drop down list populated with the data from the Price table. I am having trouble displaying the initial values. Will post the solution when I am done through jumping all the hoops. Any other ideas are welcome.